# XSLT if-clause with param check to do sorting

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

Why do I getting error when adding the if-clause in the following code?

If I remove the if-clause in XSLT, all data can be displayed as expect.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name = "orderTag1"/>
<xsl:param name = "orderTag2"/>
<xsl:param name = "orderType1"/>
<xsl:param name = "orderType2"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <table>
    <xsl:for-each select="*/item">
        <xsl:if test="$orderTag1 != ''">
            <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$orderTag1]" order="{$orderType1}"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$orderTag2 != ''">
            <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$orderTag2]" order="{$orderType2}"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Javascript

```
var xsl = loadXMLDoc("my_xml_transformer.xsl");
var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("my_xml.xml");
var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "orderTag1", "type");
xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "orderTag2", "StationName");
xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "orderType1", "ascending");
xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "orderType2", "ascending");
var resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document);
document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(resultDocument);
```

Edit ~

Im using notepad and chrome to develop a javascript website to sort data when orderTag1 or 2 is set.

Edit ~

Modified to place the if clause outside for-each. Problem fixed.

```
<xsl:if test="$orderTag1 != '' and $orderTag2 = ''">
    <xsl:for-each select="*/item">
        <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$orderTag1]" order="{$orderType1}"/>
            <tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what error you are actually getting, but it should be an error along the lines of `'xsl:sort' cannot be a child of the 'xsl:if' element.`. This means exactly what it says. `xsl:sort` should be a child of either `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:apply-templates`, not `xsl:if`.

You also didn't say what you were trying to achieve with your XSLT, but it looks like you want your sorting to be configurable, based on parameters. If so, you can just do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="*/item">
    <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$orderTag1]" order="{$orderType1}"/>
    <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$orderTag2]" order="{$orderType2}"/>
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If `$orderTag1` and `$orderTag2` and not specified, then no node will match, and nothing will be sorted. The only thing to bear on mind is that there need to be default values for the orderTypes

```
<xsl:param name = "orderType1" select="'ascending'" />
<xsl:param name = "orderType2" select="'ascending'" />
```

For example, try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name = "orderTag1"/>
<xsl:param name = "orderTag2"/>
<xsl:param name = "orderType1" select="'ascending'" />
<xsl:param name = "orderType2" select="'ascending'" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <table>
    <xsl:for-each select="*/item">
        <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$orderTag1]" order="{$orderType1}"/>
        <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$orderTag2]" order="{$orderType2}"/>
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, if you want to ensure the order type is always set correctly, you could be more robust, like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name = "orderTag1"/>
<xsl:param name = "orderTag2"/>
<xsl:param name = "orderType1" />
<xsl:param name = "orderType2" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <table>
    <xsl:variable name="ensureOrderType1">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$orderType1 != 'ascending' and $orderType1 != 'descending'">ascending</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$orderType1" /></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="ensureOrderType2">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$orderType2 != 'ascending' and $orderType2 != 'descending'">ascending</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$orderType2" /></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>


    <xsl:for-each select="*/item">
        <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$orderTag1]" order="{$ensureOrderType1}"/>
        <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$orderTag2]" order="{$ensureOrderType2}"/>
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor description. Im using notepad and chrome to develop a javascript website to sort data when orderTag1 or 2 is set. Chrome does not show any error in console and only returns an empty page, so I dont know what exactly the error is. W3School just states that <xsl:sort> element should inside the <xsl:for-each>. Thankyou so much for your answer! How do you know 'xsl:sort' cannot be a child of the 'xsl:if' element?

Comment: Try testing you XSLT at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/. For example: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqf

Comment: Thank you so much! It is so frustrating to find out a bug without error. It really helps a lot!!!